# About Constrained Speeds

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, velocity, rigid-body-dynamics, constrained-dynamics

My question is whether there is any known method, which doesn't use calculus, to find the speed of ball C, given that the speeds of balls A and B are given at a certain moment in time. Suppose that in the figure below the triangle is equilateral, the balls have equal masses and the rods are rigid and ideal.

[image]

Comment: "the speeds of balls A and B are given at a certain moment in time." B's speed isn't given. But it can be calculated.

Answer (score 2):

If the rods are rigid, then there's no relative motion between balls $A$ and $C$ or between balls $B$ and $C$ or between balls $A$ and $B$ when resolving along $AC$, $BC$ or $AB$ respectively. Use this fact to first find the velocity of ball $B$ and hence components of the velocity of ball $C$ along $AC$ and $BC$.For example,
$$\lvert \vec{v}_{B}\rvert \cos \beta = \lvert \vec{v}_{A}\rvert \cos \alpha $$ because $AB$ is constant. Use the same condition for $AC$ and $BC$.

Comment: first of all, thanks! Can I say that the velocity of C along AC is zero because of $v_A$ is perpendicular to AC, and in this case the resultant velocity of C is the one along BC?

Comment: That does seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that the triangle rotates about it's center, then since you are interested in the *speed* of ball C, the condition of the system subjected to the constraint of rigid bodies implies that the speed of all three balls must be the same as with the others, viz. $v$. Now, if you want to know the *velocity* then you also want to know the angle at which the velocity of the ball C points, since the triangle's base is parallel to the indicated line with which respect the other angles are known, the angle for C is 180 degrees.